# jquery datepicker returning a double year i.e. 05-01-20102010

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        yearRange: 'c-70:c+10',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: "/images/scw.gif"; ?>',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});

<input type='text' name='from_date' id='from_date' class='datepicker'>
<input type='text' name='to_date' id='to_date' class='datepicker'>
```

Comment: it looks like you've got a semicolon followed by ?>', is that in your actual working code?

Comment: Your code (minus the last three options, including the invalid `buttonImage` value) works fine: http://jsbin.com/izezu/2 So I would check other things on the page if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce this with a recent version of jQuery with a date format of

```
{
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
}
```

Consider yy to be a full 4 digits year.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Is this the only instance of `.datepicker` invocation in your script? Are there any calls? Is this using a custom locale thats not en? Do you have a link?

Are you sure its not `yyyy` instead of `yy`?

Comment: `mm-dd-yy` is the correct format for a full year: 2010, etc: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

Comment: Looks like it was a caching issue since the data is on a remote server.  Thanks for the answer it really is correct as yy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was because I called `jQuery().datepicker()` twice.

Comment: It's not clear if you are indeed answering the question or just stating an observation.